# Are Men above Women in Islam?

Tags: quran, women

According to Quran women are created for men. Their existences is based on comfort for men.
“And one of His signs is that He created mates for you from yourselves that you may find rest in them, and He put between you love and compassion; most surely there are signs in this for a people who reflect.” (Al-Rum : 21)
[Nisa 4:34] Men are in charge of women, as Allah has made one of them superior to the other, and because men spend their wealth for the women; so virtuous women are the reverent ones, guarding behind their husbands the way Allah has decreed guarding; and the women from whom you fear disobedience, (at first) advise them and (then) do not cohabit with them, and (lastly) beat them; then if they obey you, do not seek to do injustice to them; indeed Allah is Supreme, Great.

Most of the Quran is addressed to men and many hadith as well says only about men.
If men goes to jannah he will have jannah wine,garden and hurs as well. Is there anything for women. My question are
What is the status of women according to quran ?
Why Quran is addressed to men all time except few places?

Comment: Why do you think Men are above Women in Islam? They are treated with justice and will be judged with justice. `Abu Huraira reported that a person came to Allah, 's Messenger (may peace be upon him) and said: Who among the people is most deserving of a fine treatment from my hand? He said: Your mother. He again said: Then who (is the next one)? He said: Again it is your mother (who deserves the best treatment from you). He said: Then who (is the next one)? He (the Holy Prophet) said: Again, it is your mother. He (again) said: Then who? Thereupon he said: Then it is your father.`

Comment: What do you mean by 'above'?  As in better?

Comment: No, both are equal ( if not talking about any context). Also, both are not identical, in many ways, physically, emotionally, mentally etc. There are differences in rights and duties.. Mutually complement to each other to make it equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1**.I'd like to ask you a simple question: Why do you always say (human) NOT (huwoman) when talking about people in general? Are you implying that WOMEN are not among human beings?!!

**2**.Considering the above-mentioned point, we can understand the reason why the majority of the verbs and pronouns have been used for MEN not WOMEN. For instance let's take a look at the verse 21 of Surah Al-Rum as you cited in your question:

> **وَ مِنْ آياتِهِ أَنْ خَلَقَ لَكُمْ مِنْ أَنْفُسِكُمْ أَزْواجاً لِتَسْكُنُوا إِلَيْها وَ جَعَلَ بَيْنَكُمْ مَوَدَّةً وَ رَحْمَةً إِنَّ
>   في‏ ذلِكَ لَآياتٍ لِقَوْمٍ يَتَفَكَّرُونَ**
>
> And of His signs is that He created for you **mates** from your own selves
>   that you may take comfort in them, and He ordained affection and mercy
>   between you. There are indeed signs in that for a people who reflect.

the word "**لکم**" means "for (all of) you weather you are men or women. That's why the correct translation of the word "**ازواجا**" is "mates" which include both husbands and wives. looking the word "**زوج**" up in an Arabic Dictionary, you can find that the definition is: both male and female when they are married. In verse 45 of Surah Al-Najm we also read:

> **وَ أَنَّهُ خَلَقَ الزَّوْجَيْنِ الذَّكَرَ وَ الْأُنْثى‏**
>
> and that it is He who created the mates, the male and the female

This question may come to the mind that " If the verse were talking about both men and women in general, it shouldn't have used the pronoun "**ها**" in the word "**لها**" which refers to "female" not "male". But the answer is simple because in Arabic "**ازواج**" is called "broken plural" and the pronouns referring to these nouns must be in form of "singular feminine".

**3**. regarding the verse 34 of Surah Nisa', I'd like you to visit the answer I posted for [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17161/interpretation-of-verse-of-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D9%91%D9%90%D8%AC%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8F-%D9%82%D9%8E%D9%88%D9%91%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%8F%D9%88%D9%86%D9%8E-%D8%B9%D9%8E%D9%84%D9%8E%D9%89-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%91%D9%90%D8%B3%D9%8E%D8%A7%D8%A1/17167#17167) a few days ago.

**4**.Concerning the verse 4 of Surah Al-Nisa', there are a few points I'd like to raise so that the meaning of the verse becomes clear:

1. The verse is talking about the wives who are **abdicating their responsibilities**. The word "**نشز**" is originally defined as a high raised land. An arrogant pride and rebellious wife who is shirking her obligations is called "**ناشزه**" because she believes to be in such an exalted position that she does not have to be accountable to anyone for anything at all.
2. Getting married involves making a serious commitment. The verse is explaining the ways through which husbands should get the wives to carry out their duties in case they fail to honor their commitments.
3. This is worth mentioning that the instructions given in the verse are applicable only if the wife fails in the obligations imposed by All-wise Lawmaker. For instance a husband has no right of compelling his wife to carry out the household chores. She is even entitled of demanding money of her husband for housekeeping and even parenting her own children.
4. The verse is giving a step-by-step instruction on how to sort out such problems. Husbands should be careful not to overstep the bounds when following these steps:

**step 1**: advising. It is undeniable that when it comes to wives and husbands whose relationship is dominated by love and passion, the way of advising is far cry from the way in which a piece of advice is given to strangers.

**step 2**: turning his back on her in the bed.

**step 3**: punishing physically. This approach should only be taken as the last resort to get a rebellious wife to fulfill her duties and prevent her from trampling further rights in the family. The physical punishment has to be inflicted in such a way that cause no breakage, wounds or bruises at all. Taking the second step while knowing that the firs one will do the job, is considered a sin let along overstepping these boundaries by causing wounds or bruises. That's why in some traditions the infallible Imam tells us to hit her by a brush stick as a physical punishment which means that if someone succeeded in getting her wife to accept her responsibilities through the lightest punishment, he would not be allowed to go any further.

**Question**: What if a husband abdicates his responsibilities? How can he be held accountable?

**Answer**: Islamic ruler is the one responsible for getting a rebellious husband to fulfill his duties within the family which sometimes involves punishing him physically.

Answer (score 1):

When the Qur'an addresses a singular person in the second person, it refers to the Prophet (saws). Otherwise, the context decides who is being addressed. The general interpretive principle is that unless there is a reason to limit the context to either men or women or specific people, it applies to both men and women. This applies to hadith as well.

The Qur'an is clear in that Paradise is for everyone regardless of race or gender, and that each shall have whatever they desire. It goes further and gives vivid examples that apply to everyone. Furthermore, it gives an example of one thing for men (*hur*), but that in no way lessens or restricts other things for other people.

Answer (score 0):

sure 4 vers 34 (im not 100% sure about the numbers, only about what i did read)
tells you, if you read the german version from rudi paret, that the man stands naturally above the woman. It doesnt tell you what this means, however there is also written, that you should (its an imperative not an permission only) beat your wife if your fear (it is enough you only fear it) that your wife could revolt against - whatever this means. 
I just want to write this as a response to the comments under your question:
"Why do you think Men are above Women in Islam?"
"What do you mean by 'above'? As in better?"
Those arent serious questions are they?
However there might be verses for the women, that are not dominating or offensive, however i cant remember reading any and i read the whole book. I hope i have a bad memory in this case.

Answer (score -2):

Jannah is also for women. Same as hurs there's a male version named Qelman (قلمان) which are handsome attractive men for women. I believe that islam has a perfect vision about men and women. Consider about the polygamy and monogamy in Islam. A man can have multiple women. Quran says men can have more than 1 women in the condition and Just in case of being righteous with all of them. Now just think how it is possible to have two women that feel happy together? It's impossible in peace of course but consider a city which 2/3 of men died in wars and number of women is way more than men? 
Easily in peace if you be rich and buy two Mercedes for both of your women buy same jewelries and providing same feeling and same time sharing they wont feel you are righteous, but within and after wars in force situations every body just want basic human needs like food dress sexual relation and a man who support them.
 even in this case they need these things more than love so it will be possible that they accept sharing men. And consider how would human being survived if men couldn't have multiple women? So Quran thought of both situations and ruled fair for those who reflect.