# is there any verse where it says men have more physical strength than women?

Tags: quran, tafseer, women, men

Assalamu Alaikum. I just want to know is there anywhere in the Quran where it clearly says that,men were given more physical strength when compared to women. if yes please explain it detailly. And if men were given more physical strength then please answer what is given more to women than men quranically?

Comment: These are two questions you should stick on one question per post and the second question seems unclear to me.

Comment: Relevant post [Are men above women in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17519/are-men-above-women-in-islam)

Comment: It would be helpful if a short answer is provided to this.  especially to the first part of my question. @Medi1Saif

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no there's no verse saying that women are given less physical strength than men.

In fact there's no verse that says men have been given something more than women nor vice versa. Both have been given duties and responsibilities and both have been reminded of their duties and responsibilities towards the other when there's something which might apply to one gender exclusively. For example when the Qur'an speaks about given birth Allah reminds the father that it is his duty to feed and cloth etc.

The long answer is that in most general purposes men and women are equal both have their duties and both are ordered to worship and do good deeds, but in some details they might differ.

And anywhere Allah has given what seems more rights to (or exceeded) men he also demanded additional duties. Men are asked to be in charge of the women they are asked to spend their wealth for them, to cloth and feed them and to work for being able to be in charge of their families.

> Men are in charge of women by [right of] what Allah has given one over the other and what they spend [for maintenance] from their wealth.  ... ([4:34](https://legacy.quran.com/4/34))

Allah has lifted this duty and other duties from the women.

---

**Side notes on this verse**

- Some scholars added in the context of this verse- other reasons for the supposed accentuation on men like prophet hood etc..
- Others pointed at the fact that the statement is general and doesn't necessarily exclude the existence of women who may excel men at some deeds or acts etc. So this verse may apply for a majority of women, but there are indeed women who are stronger than some men and who would be able to do whatever men are able to do.
- Some scholars considered not being able to be in charge of the family for a husband as a reason for his wife to nullify the marriage!

---

And what ever each of them does for the other is a graciousness none of both should deny.

> ... And do not forget graciousness between you. Indeed Allah , of whatever you do, is Seeing. ([2:237](https://legacy.quran.com/2/237))

That's why Allah also says:

> ... And due to the wives is similar to what is expected of them, according to what is reasonable. But the men have a degree over them [in responsibility and authority].  ... ([2:228](https://legacy.quran.com/2/228))

While in most other verses of the Qur'an we are faced to verses addressing both genders equally like in:

- > And it is He who produced you from one soul and [gave you] a place of dwelling and of storage. We have detailed the signs for a people who understand. ([6:98](https://legacy.quran.com/6/98))

saying both genders have one origin, so they have basically same conditions!

- > And We have certainly honored the children of Adam and carried them on the land and sea and provided for them of the good things and preferred them over much of what We have created, with [definite] preference. ([17:70](https://legacy.quran.com/17/70))

saying both genders and humans in general have been preferred over all other creations.

- > O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made you peoples and tribes that you may know one another. Indeed, the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted. ([49:13](https://legacy.quran.com/49/13))

saying by default everybody -in particular both genders- is equal by Allah the only measurement that makes a distinction is the righteousness (taqwa).

- > And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me. ([51:56](https://legacy.quran.com/51/56))

saying that all humans (male and female) are created to worship Allah!