# Quran and equality

Tags: quran, equality

Asalaamu Alaykum WARAhmATULLAAHI wabarakaatuhu

1. If I ask this question it doesn't mean that I left islam right (btw I'm 12)
   Ok so why does Allah say Arijaalu Kawaamuna alnisaa men are superior to women
   When islam is all about equality

Comment: See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbCUxALJngI)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [interpretation of verse of ' الرِّجَالُ قَوَّامُونَ عَلَى النِّسَاء'?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17161/17163) or [Are Men above Women in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17519/17163)

Answer (score 0):

Islam is not a religion of equality but of Justice. Equality implies no differentiation between the two. Men and women are different. Can men get pregnant? Can we put male and female in the same boxing ring? Islam is the religion of justice, Justice is about using things for what they have been created for. Not one single letter in the Qur’an enjoins equality, rather it enjoins justice.

> “Verily, Allah enjoins Al‘Adl (i.e. justice)” (Qur’an, 16:90)

> “Say: Are those who know equal to those who know not?” (Qur’an, 39:9)

Answer (score 0):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

This is how Allah created human beings. Verse 34 of Sura Nisa, chapter 4, of Quran is as clear as daylight,

> **Men are guardians of the women due to what Allah has Made some of them
> to excel others** and because they are spending from their wealth.
>
> [Quran 4:34, Tafseer Hub-e-Ali, page 33](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH4_SuraNisaa_Verses22-41.pdf)

In following Hadith narration Muhammad (saww) explains the superiority of men over women

> from his grandfather Al-Hassan (asws) Bin Ali Bin Abu Talib (asws)
> having said: ‘A number of Jews came to Rasool-Allah (saww) and asked
> him (asws) certain questions, and from what they asked him (asws) was,
> ‘**What is the excellence of the man over the woman?**’
>
> So the Prophet (saww) said: ‘Like the excellence of the sky over the
> earth, and like the water over the earth, for the water revives the
> earth, and by the men, the women are revived. And had it not been for
> the men, Allah (azwj ) would not have Created the women. Allah (azwj)
> is Saying **Men are guardians of the women due to what Allah has Made
> some of them to excel others and because they are spending from their
> wealth [4:34]**’.
>
> The Jew said, ‘By which thing is it like this?’ So the Prophet (saww)
> said: ‘Allah (azwj) Mighty and Majestic Created Adam (as) from clay,
> and Created Hawwa (as) from its remnant, and the first one who obeyed
> Adam (as) was the woman. So Allah (azwj) Mighty and Majestic Made them
> descend from the Garden, and Explained the excellence of the man over
> the woman in the world. Have you not seen the women how they
> menstruate and it is not possible for them to worship due to the
> filth, and the men are not affected with anything from the
> menstruation?’
>
> The Jew said, ‘You (saww) have spoken the truth, O Muhammad (saww)’
>
> [Quran 4:34, Tafseer Hub-e-Ali, page 34](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/TafseerHub-e-Ali/CH4_SuraNisaa_Verses22-41.pdf)

Superiority of men over women is also reflected in Fiqh, Islamic Jurisprudence, such as

- Women inherit half of what men inherit;
- Women can not voluntarily fast without the permission of her husband;
- Prerogative to declare Talaq to divorce is in the hand of husband - man, not wife - woman;
- Man have more right over children than woman;

Comment: You don't know the meaning of word slave? Nobody is slave of Prophet or Imam. We are not Abdul Nabi or Abdur Rasool or Abdul Imam. Rather we are AbdaAllah. We are slaves of Allah.